# Autocomplete text from pre-selected option into input

Tags: javascript, html, css

am trying to implement an Autocomplete text function where you selected a part of the string from the option..

Your supposed to first select what type of drink your looking for, counting by typing characters after yor hav selectet in "option"

begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false

language: lang-html

```js
function insertFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = x;
}

function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  var currentFocus;
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    var a, b, i, val = this.value;
    closeAllLists();
    if (!val) {
      return false;
    }
    currentFocus = -1;
    a = document.createElement("DIV");
    a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
    this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
        b = document.createElement("DIV");
        b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
        b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
        b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
        b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

          closeAllLists();
        });
        a.appendChild(b);
      }
    }
  });

  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      currentFocus++;
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
      currentFocus--;
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (currentFocus > -1) {
        if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
      }
    }
  });

  function addActive(x) {
    if (!x) return false;

    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }

  function removeActive(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }

  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}


var drinks = ["Alcoholic - Beer", "Alcoholic - By country", "Alcoholic - Cider", "Alcoholic - Distilled", "Alcoholic - Cocktails", "Alcoholic - Hard soda", "Alcoholic - Wine", "Alcoholic - Caffeinated", "Alcoholic - Chocolate", "Alcoholic - Historic", "Alcoholic - Plant-based", "Alcoholic - Barley", "Alcoholic - Maize", "Alcoholic - Rice", "Alcoholic - Barley", "Alcoholic - Hot drinks", "Alcoholic - Mixed drinks", "Non-Alcoholic - Beer", "Non-Alcoholic - By country", "Non-Alcoholic - Cider", "Non-Alcoholic - Distilled", "Non-Alcoholic - Cocktails", "Non-Alcoholic - Hard soda", "Non-Alcoholic - Wine", "Non-Alcoholic - Caffeinated", "Non-Alcoholic - Chocolate", "Non-Alcoholic - Historic", "Non-Alcoholic - Plant-based", "Non-Alcoholic - Barley", "Non-Alcoholic - Maize", "Non-Alcoholic - Rice",
  "Non-Alcoholic - Barley", "Non-Alcoholic - Hot drinks", "Non-Alcoholic - Mixed drinks"
];


autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput2"), drinks);
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), drinks);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 16px Arial;
}

.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[type=text] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}

.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.autocomplete-active {
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<p>Select:</p>
<select id="mySelect" onchange="insertFunction()" size="4">
  <option value=" "> </option>
  <option value="Alcoholic">Alcoholic</option>
  <option value="Non-Alcoholic">Non-Alcoholic</option>
  <option value="Alcoholic - Cocktails">Happy Hour Specials</option>
</select>


<h2>Autocomplete</h2>


<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myDrink" placeholder="Drikns">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, and what's the problem?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for <datalist>.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way, by adding each category in an array, its much cleaner..

```js
function autocomplete(inp, arra) {
 

 
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
       var arr = arra[mySelect]
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
     
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {

    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}
var list = {
  alcoholic : [ "Beer", 
  "By country", 
  "Cider", 
  "Distilled", 
  "Cocktails", 
  "Hard soda", 
  "Wine", 
  "Caffeinated", 
  "Chocolate", 
  "Historic", 
  "Plant-based",
  "Barley", 
  "Maize", 
  "Rice", 
  "Barley", 
  "Hot drinks", 
  "Mixed drinks"],
  non_alcoholic : [
  "Beer",
  "By country", 
  "Cider", 
  "Distilled", 
  
  "Cocktails",
  "Hard soda", 
  "Wine", 
  "Caffeinated",
  "Chocolate", 
  "Historic", 
  "Plant-based", 
  "Barley", 
  "Maize", 
  "Rice",
  "Barley", 
  "Hot drinks", 
  "Mixed drinks"
   ],
  happy_hower : [
    "Beer",
    "By country", 
    "Cider", 
    "Distilled"
  ]
  
}


/*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), list);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 16px Arial;
}

.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[type=text] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}

.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.autocomplete-active {
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<p>Select:</p>
<select id="mySelect"  size="4">
  <option value=" "> </option>
  <option value="alcoholic">Alcoholic</option>
  <option value="non_alcoholic">Non-Alcoholic</option>
  <option value="happy_hower">Happy Hour Specials</option>
</select>


<h2>Autocomplete</h2>


<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, like it, is there a way to geting the an respons by the EventListener when selecting option value?  hence listing all variables responding to the chosen option /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/

Comment: You can call a function inside the event listener.. Plese if you finde my answer abowe as correct, consider marking it as a correct answer